# Is It possible to Linking static library into dynamic library in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, static-libraries

I am try to link a static library in a dynamic library tmxParser.lib in Visual Studio 2010 express. I have the static library set as a dependency of the dynamic library. When VS build the static library builds fine and creates tmxParser.lib. When VS builds the dynamic library I am getting linker errors. I tried to match the Runtime Library under property page -> Configuration properties -> C/C++ -> Code Generation
It doesn't help. Anyone have any idea?

```
2>LIBCMTD.lib(fopen.obj) : error LNK2005: _fopen already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_stdio.obj)
2>LIBCMTD.lib(open.obj) : error LNK2005: __open already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_win32.obj)
2>LIBCMTD.lib(open.obj) : error LNK2005: __sopen already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_win32.obj)
2>LIBCMTD.lib(chsize.obj) : error LNK2005: __chsize already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_win32.obj)
2>LIBCMTD.lib(read.obj) : error LNK2005: __read already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_win32.obj)
2>LIBCMTD.lib(close.obj) : error LNK2005: __close already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_win32.obj)
2>LIBCMTD.lib(lseek.obj) : error LNK2005: __lseek already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_win32.obj)
2>LIBCMTD.lib(setmode.obj) : error LNK2005: __setmode already defined in s3e_d.lib(iwcrt_win32.obj)
```

Comment: You'd best use their dedicated forum: http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/devnet/forum/general

Comment: Thanks for you respond. I already tried their forum but got no respond.

Comment: Yes, that's typical.  Promises of "runs anywhere!" are inversely proportional to support and your luck with tinkering with the execution model.

Answer (score 0):

When you say you have it set as a dependency, do you mean you have it set as a Project Dependency or is under "Additional Dependencies" in

`Project Properties -> Librarian->General -> Additional Dependencies`

Answer (score 0):

Generally, yes.

The problem you have seems to be that the library (is it the [marmalade library](http://www.madewithmarmalade.com/marmalade)?) implements some of the methods from the C++ runtime library. Probably, this lib is supposed to be used without linking the standard runtime library.

Possible solutions:

- do not link c++ runtime in your DLL. That should be possible if you write just a thin wrapper
- Ask the guys making the lib how they thought this is supposed to work
- use the lib.exe or dumpbin.exe to:

  - extract all .obj files of the lib
  - remove the conflicting symbols from the .obj files
  - recreate the lib

The latter is obviously an ugly hack, and should be reserved for cases where neither source nor original developer are available anymore.

Comment: thanks for the help. The reason I think tmxParser being a static library was because When I can the output type of the dynamic library from a dll to static libray(.lib) all the linker error is gone. But the application would error at runtime. I ended up just including the source of the tmxParser in the main application. Although I had to change the tmxParser code so it doesn't require the standard runtime library.